# GIthub Api get all commits per repo of user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-api

I am trying to use Github API  to get all commits of user. Github API doesn't explicitly provide this, so the only way is to loop through all the repos and find number of commits authored by the user for each repo.
The idea for getting this is

```
for each repo in repoList:  
    response = https://api.github.com/repos/{user}/{repo_name}/commits?per_page=100&page={page}
    for each item in response:
        if(item.commit.author===user)
            totalCommmitsPerRepo += 1
    update state as {repo : totalCommitsPerRepo}
```

(Max results per page = 100)

I am having problems when updating the page number. My code is given below

```
getCommitsInfo = async = () => {
    let flag = 0
    const repos = [...this.state.repos]
    let totalCommits = 0
    const requests = repos.map((repo) => {
            do {
                flag = 0;
                axios.get("https://api.github.com/repos/" + this.state.user + '/' + repo + "/commits?per_page=100&page=" + page)
                    .then(res => {
                        totalCommits = 0
                        //CHECK IF RESULTS PER PAGE = MAXIMUM
                        if (res.data.length === 100) {
                            flag = 1
                        }
                        res.data.map(commit => {
                            let committer = commit.author.login.toLowerCase()
                            let user = this.state.user.toLowerCase()
                            if (user === committer) {
                                totalCommits += 1
                            }
                        })
                        let obj = {
                            name: repo,
                            commits: totalCommits
                        }
                        this.setState({
                            reposAndCommits: [...this.state.reposAndCommits, obj]
                        })
                    })
                //UPDATE PAGE NUMBER
                if (flag) {
                    page += 1
                }
            } while (flag);
        })
    await Promise.all(requests)
}
```

The do while loop doesn't seem to work as expected. I am not getting the page number updated. This is possibly because the do-while loop is asynchronous and I don't know how to make the loop wait until each response is fully complete.
Can someone please help regarding this, Thanks

Comment: you can filter by author using the `author` param : https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits. From your code it seems you only need to count commits authored by a specific user, is that correct ?

Comment: @BertrandMartel Oh thanks I didn't notice that. However now when I try to add author in the url, I am getting empty data. Possibly because I'm not using it correctly and there's no example on the docs :(. Could you please give an example for the GET url with the `author` param